# How can i add depth=1 to BaseSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

ModelSerializer have a depth in Meta

```
class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = None
        depth = 2
        fields = '__all__'
```

any alternative in BaseSerializer?

Comment: What is `BaseSerializer` here? You can implement such serializer and specify a `depth = 1` yes.

Comment: any example? sorry i am new in django

Comment: An alternative to do what?

Comment: depth (child object not yet id)